# What determines how fast you revive someone in Guild Wars 2

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, you are able to revive other downed players and pets/NPC allies. To revive someone, you channel the revive skill and as you channel the skill, the person or animal you are channeling revive on gets ticks of health back until the revive bar reaches full. When it reaches full the person or animal is revived with half health.

I noticed that on different occasions the health ticks to revive someone is different. Sometimes it takes only a couple seconds to revive while other times it takes up to 20 seconds or so. What affects how fast you revive someone?

Comment: Do note that it is possible for multiple people to revive someone at once - and each contribution stacks, so that might be *one* issue for the varying rates.

Comment: downed people res faster than dead people.  And some classes have a downed skill that boost res rate as well.

Comment: I also noticed that you revive someone slower if you are being attacked.

Answer (score 7):

Revival and it's speed is based on several factors:

1. Your health when you are reviving someone (Faster when you have more health to give)
2. Your experience level (More Experience = More Health to start with)
3. The number of people helping to revive the downed player (Revival is the sum of all people working to bring you back)
4. If the player you are reviving has a "downed penalty" (Slower recovery time and reduced per person revival

A player will "Rally" when 25% of their overall heath has been returned to them either through player revival or other skills. You also gain a little experience for reviving someone.

The easiest way to see the difference starting with more health makes is to head to PvP and do the Revive a Player Heart Task. Since you are automatically set to level 80 when you enter you can see the per second revival stat at it's maximum vs when you go back to PvE and it adjusts to your Health/Experience combo.

The [Revival page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Revival) on the wiki talks to the process but not so much the exact per second calculation.

Comment: This answer isn't quite complete without mentioning in-combat vs out-of-combat revival.

Comment: Parts 1, 2, and 4 of this answer are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in number that you're seeing is because you will [revive](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Revival) other characters approximately 3x as fast when you're not in combat compared to when you are.

The amount healed with each "tick" depends on that character's maximum health. [Dynamic level adjustment](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dynamic_level_adjustment) keeps this fairly consistent between players and NPCs within any given area.

A character will be revived from either [downed](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Downed) or [defeated](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defeated) state when their health reaches 25% full.

Other players or NPCs can help you revive the downed or defeated character, and that character can also help with skills such as [Bandage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bandage) if they are merely downed.

There are also certain runes and traits that can speed up revival, such as the [Fast Healer](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fast_Healer) trait or a [Rune of Mercy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rune_of_Mercy).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an effect to enhance the time, I think it's a standard time frame. As mentioned by Raven though, it does get quicker the more people who help.

I think this is to maintain balance with skills like [Signet of Mercy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_Mercy) and [Glyph of Renewal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glyph_of_Renewal) otherwise it would making taking a rez skill quite pointless. [More Revive skills](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Revival).

I've also noticed that the time frame is the same and the % of health is what changes, so healing a lv5 you might get ticks of 8hp but on a lv23 you'd get a few hundred.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it might be faster for a high level character to revive a lower level character and likewise it might take longer for a lower level character to revive a higher level character.

Comment: @Jay Ah I see. Would need an experiment organising in BWE2

Comment: You also rez someone faster out of combat than in. Not sure about exact %'s though.

Answer (score 1):

My experience was that the time taken to revive someone was standard, and the only way to do it faster was to get a second person helping. I also found that the amount of HP trickling in per tick was scaled off the max health of the target being revived. Some things got 50+ a tick, some lowbie NPCs got 5-7.